# Elasticsearch https and Nest client connection with ssl certificate

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I am trying to implement Elasticsearch 5.x with https(using Safeguard) and NEST client.

I am failing on, how to generate a X509certificate of Elasticsearch installed in server.

Found some code in below link how to create a NEST connection to Elasticsearch with X509 certificate.

[How to use X509 certificate with the Nest Elastic Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237405/how-to-use-x509-certificate-with-the-nest-elastic-client)

But I have no idea how to achieve this. I need to know how the below things:

1. How to generate a X509 certificate of Elasticsearch 5.x(Elasticsearch installed in a server and is accessible through some url like https://elas:9300)
2. What could be the value for "path_to_cert" in the above link's answer(I understood it is the path to X509 certificate file). It need to be a shared path or that certificate need to be included in application

I tried searching all the web and still no idea. Please help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear if it is about the Elasticsearch server to configure, or only the client. Is the server already running with SSL (is it reachable at https://elas:9300 ?). If no, then you need to create a java keystore containing a self-signed certificate (I suppose it's enough for your need). If already running in SSL and your question is only about the client, then store the certificate that you can get when browsing https://elas:9300 in this file that you suggested (path_to_cert)

Comment: Thank you.

My question is about client only. The server already running with SSL and I am able to access the elatic url(https://elas:9300). 

But I have no idea how to save/get the X509 cert file from elastic host and include in "path_to_cert" of a client request.

Comment: You can use any browser and go to https://elas:9300, clic on the lock on the address bar, display the certificate, and export it to a file. It will give a file with text that you can copy / paste or transfer where your client is running.

Comment: Thank you. But it generates a client certificate for specific client user(here myself). Then does it will work if the client application is hosted and used by multiple users?

Comment: no it doesn't generate a client certificate, but it exports the server certificate that you can use anywhere when you need such certificate verification. Multiple users can use it.